# Read Only Schema with Feathers.js and Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I am using Feathers.js with Sequelize to create a REST API for my MySQL database. Everything seems to work for GET operations. However I am getting the following error in the console:

```
error: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise  {"_bitField":18087936,"_fulfillmentHandler0":{"name":"SequelizeDatabaseError","parent":{"code":"ER_TABLEACCESS_DENIED_ERROR","errno":1142,"sqlState":"42000","sqlMessage":"CREATE command denied to user 'f_admin'@'localhost' for table 'f_sales'"...
```

I think Sequelize is wanting to make changes to my schema but I don't want it to do that. How can set it up so that the I can CRUD records but not make changes to the schema?

Comment: are you calling `sync()`?

Comment: Yes, I am calling sync(). Should I not?

Comment: no, you should not. it is what is trying to create the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call [`Sequelize.sync()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-sync) and Sequelize won't try to create any tables.